# Pointer assignments in a copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, c++11, memory-management

I'm using the book *Programming with objects* by Avinash C. KAK, and in the page 452, it says constructs a copy constructor method as

```
class X{
int * ptr;
int size;
public:
X(const X & xobj)
{
    size = xobj.size;
    ptr = new int [size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = xobj.ptr[i];
    }   
}
}
```

Then it uses as

```
X x1;
X x2 = x1;
```

But what I did not understand is that first it allocates memory for the x2.ptr and then assigns the memory address of x1.ptr to x2.ptr, which contradicts with the purpose of having a copy constructor method and the newly allocated memory is now not being used at all, so what am I missing ?

Comment: Why do you think the memory is not used? There's no assignment from `ptr` to `ptr`, only the contents are copied

Comment: but then shouldn't we use as  ´´*obj.ptr[i]´ ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It's a normal array access.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so the way that has been done is the formal and the proper way of doing this ?

Comment: Yes. It allocates a new array and copies the existing object's contents into it so there are now two identical objects sewage from each other.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen For a C developer this is absolutely a weird thing :).Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pointer to a newly allocated array like:

```
ptr = new int[size];
```

then you can index it in the same way as the arrays:

```
ptr[1] = 3; // equivalent to: *(ptr + 1) = 3
```

So, as it's a copy constructor it copies the content of memory pointed by `xobj.ptr` to the newly allocated memory pointed by `ptr`.